# Habilitar Extension de SQL Sever en PHP 4.7.13

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

Estoy tratando de configurar pdo_sqlsrv en IIS pero no lo logo habilitar esta opcion,
estoy utilizando  IIS version 6.2 corriendo en Windows server 2012 R2, La version de PHP es la 7.4.13 NTS.

he copiado los drivers de la version 7.4 NTS en la ruta correspondiente C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.4\ext\ , cabe mencionar que la version de los drivers es la 5.9

Drivers:
php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll
php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll

y configurado el archivo php.ini agregando estas dos lineas.

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll
```

Pero aun no logro habilitar SQLSRV en mi servidor.

Alguna idea de que puedo estar haciendo mal o que puedo estar omitiendo.

Comment: Revisa el orden: `php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll`, `php_pdo.dll`, `php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll`. Y no olvides reiniciar IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi problema era que al instalar PHP desde Microsoft web plataform Installer instale 2 (versiones de PHP) y digo versiones por que se instalo PHP y PHP for IIS Express, entonces en el PHP manager de IIS tenia configurado el PHP for IIS Express y no el PHP normal, yo estaba configurando y agregando los drivers para la version completa de PHP y no de PHP for IIS Express :), asi que fue error de capa 8.

Saludos a todos.